# How to set the value of a field based on other field values before save

Tags: laravel, model, field, laravel-backpack

I have a table called students that has first_name, last_name and full_name columns. I want the value of full_name to be set with `first_name .' '. last_name` before the values are saved to the database.

Is `public function store(StoreRequest $request)` the best place and what is the required code?

```
        $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => "First Name",
        'tab' => 'Details'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => "Last Name",
        'tab' => 'Details'
        ]);

        $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'full_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        ]);



        // add asterisk for fields that are required in StudentRequest
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(StoreRequest::class, 'create');
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(UpdateRequest::class, 'edit');
        $this->crud->allowAccess('show');

    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        // your additional operations before save here

        $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
        // your additional operations after save here
        // use $this->data['entry'] or $this->crud->entry
        return $redirect_location;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the content of the crud class? does it work as a repository? Imho, you are adding complexity to what is a simple procedure. Alternative, you don't need to store `full_name` as column, you can compute this attribute based on the other two column using [Accesors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

Comment: Thanks. The reason I want to store the full_name is so I can use it as the [attribute to show](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-fields#select2) when selecting the student 1-n relationship with records from another table. The crud class is as per [backpack](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/CrudController.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the proper ways to do this is to use laravel eloquent model events.

You can use the `creating` event of the `Student` model. The `creating` event occurs right before the model is saved to the database.

You can bind the creating event of the student model in the `AppServiceProvider` `boot` function

**AppServiceProvider**

```
use App\Models\Student;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Student::creating(function ($student) {
            $student->full_name = $student->first_name.' '.$student->last_name;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes an error: "Class 'App\Providers\Student' not found".

Comment: It is your Student model. it need to be imported in the `AppServiceProveder`.
example `use App\Student;`